# Problem with local variables when using Module twice in the same code

Tags: warning-messages, scoping, variable-definitions, code-review

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
g1[K1_, K2_, K3_] := 
  Module[{w, e}, Subscript[C, 1] = K1/2; Subscript[C, 2] = K2/2; 
   Subscript[C, 3] = K3/3; ω = K1 + K2 + K3; 
   w = (Subscript[C, 1]*Subscript[C, 2]*Subscript[C, 3])/ω; 
   e = ω*w ; Return[{w, e}]];
a = g1[10, 15, 20]
g2[K1_, K2_, K3_] := 
  Module[{w, e}, e1 = (Subscript[C, 1]*K1*K2)/2; 
   e2 = (K2*K3*Subscript[C, 2])/2; 
   e3 = (Subscript[C, 2]*K3*K2 + K1)/3; 
   f1 = D[e1, {Subscript[C, 1]}]; f2 = D[e2, {Subscript[C, 2]}]; 
   f3 = D[e3, {Subscript[C, 3]}]; w = (e1 + e2 + e3); 
   e = 30*w ; Return[{w, e}]];
b = g2[10, 15, 20]
```

I have written two `Module` in the same program. The variable I am finding in the first `Module` is there in the second `Module`. I used `clear[c1,c2,c3]` I turned out not working. How to implement two module in the same program. The above is the simple replica of the error I am getting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Error

Your error is in

```
f1 = D[e1, {Subscript[C, 1]}]
```

and it is not related to the [`Module`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html), but to the fact you have already defined a value for `Subscript[C, 1]` in this case `5`, and you can not take the derivative with respect to `5`.

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

### Solution

`Module` would play a role in the solution and not the problem if you had use it to make `c1,c2,c3` local, like

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
g1[K1_, K2_, K3_] := Module[{w, e , c1, c2, c3},
   c1 = K1/2;
   c2 = K2/2;
   c3 = K3/3; 
   ω = K1 + K2 + K3;
   w = (c1*c2*c3)/om;
   e = ω*w; Return[{w, e}]];
a = g1[10, 15, 20]
g2[K1_, K2_, K3_] := Module[
   {w, e, c1, c2, c3},
   e1 = (c1*K1*K2)/2;
   e2 = (K2*K3*c2)/2;
   e3 = (c3*K3*K2 + K1)/3;
   f1 = D[e1, {c1}];
   f2 = D[e2, {c2}];
   f3 = D[e3, {c3}];
   w = (e1 + e2 + e3)/om;
   e = 30*w; Return[{w, e}]];
b = g2[10, 15, 20]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Documentation

You should read the *"Details"* section in [the documentation for `Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html). Because `Module` creates a symbol with name `xxx$nnn` to represent a local variable with name `xxx`, it doesn't matter if `xxx` is defined outside, all local evaluations will use a [temporary variable](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Temporary.html) `xxx$nnn` (notice the output).

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

### Side Note

You should avoid using [`Subscript`](https://wolfr.am/vxtW3QtE) while defining symbols (variables). `Subscript[C, 1]` is not a symbol, but a composite expression where `Subscript` is an operator without built-in meaning. You expect to do $C_1=5$ but you are actually doing `Set[Subscript[C, 1], 5]` which is to assign a [`DownValues`](https://wolfr.am/vxtQt6LX) to the operator `Subscript` and not an `OwnValues` to an indexed `C` as you may intend. Read how to [properly define indexed variables here](https://wolfr.am/vxtT6JDX)

Comment: Actually, in my original code, I am actually finding the values of  `c1 c2 c3`  using the first module. But in the second module, I have to do some operation which involves taking derivatives wrt  `c1 c2 c3`. Since `c1 c2 c3` are the local variables in the first module. I don't have to worry about taking derivatives wrt `c1 c2 c3` in the second module. Is it right?

Comment: @vijay yes, see my edit.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I implemented in my main code and it worked.